# What's the easiest way to share an image from a GDK app?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

My GDK app generates an image that I'd like the user to share with other people.

I tried creating a Card that contained an image and inserted it into the timeline.  There is no Share menu item for that card.

I also tried adding the image into the Media Gallery and that does not produce an error but the image does not appear in the timeline:

```
Uri result = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
```

And lastly I've tried the ACTION_SEND intent which doesn't seem to be supported:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

So what's the right way to do this?

--edit

A couple more things I've tried unsuccessfully :

-Upload to Amazon S3.  It doesn't look like I can use the Amazon .jar file in a GDK app.  The app builds but I get a ClassNotFoundException on runtime.

-use the JavaMail API to mail that image to a specific email address.  It doesn't look like some of the required classes for JavaMail are included in the GDK environment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they haven't enabled this functionality yet. I've been waiting for them to add the ability for a menu action like share or send or open website to a card insert from GDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I've got a solution here.  I can post the image to a service and then on the backend do whatever I need to do with it.   I had to Base64 encode the image content b/c as far as I can tell it doesn't look like Multipart is supported.  Wrap this bad boy in an AsyncTask and you should be good to go:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myservicetodothis.com/");

    byte[] contentBytes = <bytes from image go here>;

    String encodedFile = Base64.encodeToString(contentBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileBytes", encodedFile));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.i(TAG, "HTTP Response is : " + response);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a 'Share' system menu exists, but if you want to push a card on the timeline, you should probably use the TimelineManager class, that allow you to interact with the Glass timeline :

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager#insert(com.google.android.glass.app.Card)

Be careful, you can't use the same insertion strategy if you're pushing static cards or live cards.

Julian

Comment: That was actually the first thought I had.  I tried that.  I had a Card with an image and no text and pushed it to the timeline.  The issue is that there's nothing you can do with that card as a user once it's in there.   Unless I'm doing something wrong here:       Card card2 = new Card(this);
    card2.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.FULL);
    card2.addImage(R.drawable.glass_share);
    TimelineManager.from(this).insert(card2);

Comment: Take a look at the grid here (bottom of the page) : https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/index. You can't access the user input with Static Cards. You probably should try with a Live Card. There is a good example : https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards

Comment: Ok so let's say I have a live card and I can access the user input.  How then would I share the image out other people?